# PC is not detecting any boot drive. How to fix this?

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, gparted, swap

I used gparted to shrink the swap space and add it to the drive that had Ubuntu installed in it from Live boot. After doing so, I restarted the computer and then found a black screen saying just this:
No bootable device -- insert boot disk and press any key.

Help. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I installed grub again, mounting the drive in which Linux is installed. Still, it gives the same message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. :)
Boot-Repair fixed it, with no hassles.
Here's how to get it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

I ran it and clicked Recommended repair and it fixed the problem automatically.

Basically it fixed problems with my GRUB.

Comment: Thanks. I will. Didnt think of that... Gotta wait 17 hrs though. :)